# Comparing two floats converted from string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem when comparing two floats converted from strings.
When I compare numbers with two decimal places (for example 30,25) I don't have any problem, but when the number has one place (30,6) the result is bad.

For example, the result of `30,6 > 30,25` is `false` (which I didn't expect).

```
       if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            double CyklusSAP = 0;
            double CyklusReal = 0;
            bool prevod = false;
            CyklusSAP = double.Parse(gvr.Cells[10].Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            prevod = double.TryParse(gvr.Cells[11].Text,out CyklusReal);

            if (prevod)
            {
                CyklusReal = double.Parse(gvr.Cells[11].Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                if (CyklusReal < CyklusSAP - 1)
                {
                    gvr.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                }
                if (CyklusReal > CyklusSAP - 1 && CyklusReal < CyklusSAP)
                {
                    gvr.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                }
                if (CyklusReal > CyklusSAP && CyklusReal < CyklusSAP + 1)
                {
                    gvr.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
                }
                if (CyklusReal > CyklusSAP + 1)
                {
                    gvr.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: Picture]

When is second rows bigger as first, then is the row two red.

Comment: Unrelated: What happens if `(CyklusReal == CyklusSAP + 1)` ? (or `CyklusReal == CyklusSAP - 1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the invariant culture. In invariant culture, `,` is a thousands separator, not a decimal separator. So your numbers turn out as `306` and `3 025`. You need to use the proper culture to parse the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You need use proper culture to convert comma separate decimal point to floating-point number

something like

```
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
if(double.TryParse(gvr.Cells[10].Text, style, culture, out CyklusSAP) && double.TryParse(gvr.Cells[10].Text, style, culture, out prevod))
{  
  // Your logic goes here
}
```

Bonus : Do not forget to write `using System.Globalization;`

POC : [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CcjzKC)

Comment: OP is also missing two special cases where the values are equal. That's unrelated to the question, but I think it's worth mentioning in an answer as remark. I did in comment, but that may go unseen.

Comment: @Fildor, nice to catch corner cases like this, but I believe OP is only trying to compare two values. He is not doing any opeations on it. @JakubDvorak, if You want to perform any operations on decimal values, **do it inside if condition**. If you do it before parsing then it will endup with some different values in `CyklusReal` or `CyklusSAP`

Comment: @Fildor, I added comment, if you think this is not what you want to convey, please let me know I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for your suggestions. It helped me to improve my answer